# Identity Server 4 - federated logout of google when used as an idp

Tags: identityserver4, google-identity

I have google configured as an external identity provider.  How do I configure IdentityServer to also log out of this external identity provder as well as all my client applications?

FYI, the client application sign out is already working.  Just want to log user out of google as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Anwer**

Google doesnt supprot it [Signout for Google External Identity Provider isn't working](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2066)

**Background Information:**

When a user is signing-out of IdentityServer, and they have used an external identity provider to sign-in then it is likely that they should be redirected to also sign-out of the external provider. `Not all external providers support sign-out, as it depends on the protocol and features they support.`

To detect that a user must be redirected to an external identity provider for sign-out is typically done by using a idp claim issued into the cookie at IdentityServer. The value set into this claim is the AuthenticationScheme of the corresponding authentication middleware. At sign-out time this claim is consulted to know if an external sign-out is required.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
{
    // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
    var vm = await _account.BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

    var user = HttpContext.User;
    if (user?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        // delete local authentication cookie
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

        // raise the logout event
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(user.GetSubjectId(), user.GetName()));
    }

    // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
    if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
    {
        // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
        // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
        // complete our single sign-out processing.
        string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

        // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
    }

    return View("LoggedOut", vm);
}
```

Ripped directly from the documentation [Sign-out of External Identity Providers](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout_external_providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.  On the logged out view, I added an iframe and a button, that when clicked loads the google logout url in the iframe.  This seems to be working well.